# How to resolve network error in flutter firebase auth?

Tags: flutter

I am getting this message everytime I try to signup or login in my app. I am using firebase auth.

I/flutter (11519): Error :PlatformException(ERROR_NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED, A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., null)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code it's catch-all type of exception**

```
Future<String> loginwithemailandpassword(String email,String password) async {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      UserCredential result = await firebaseauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
     if(result != null)
  {
    setState(() {
      user = result.user;
    });
    return "Success";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Unsuccess";
  }


      
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      //print(error.code);
      if (error.code == "invalid-email") {

        return "Invalid Email";
      } else if (error.code == "user-disabled") {

        return "User Disabled";
      } else if (error.code == "user-not-found") {

        return "User not found";
      } else if (error.code == "wrong-password") {

        return "Wrong Password";
      } else {

        return "Unknown Error";
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print("Socket Exception Error $e");

      return "Network Error";
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {

      print("Timeout Error $e");

      return "Timeout Error";
    } catch (e) {

      print("UnExpected Error::$e");
      return "UnExpected Error";
    }
  }
```

**Then OnPressed Write Following Code:**

```
onPressed: () async{
  //login(context);
  String message = await loginwithemailandpassword(emailC.text, passwordC.text);
  if(message == "Success")
  {
     //Do Navigate Like Following
     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Dashboard()),);
  }
  else
  {
      print(message);
  }
                                      
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try putting it around in a `try / catch` block.

This is just pseudocode, but I hope you can get the idea on how to approach it.

```
try {
   // login with facebook code
} catch (error) {
   if (error.code === 'the network error code') {
      // show dialog
   }
 }
```

Comment: how does this answer the question about resolving the problem?